# How to upload images in Flex 4 with Filereference?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, filereference

I'm trying to upload images in Flex 4 and haven't got so much success with it yet. Somebody who can help?

My code:

```
  private var fileref:FileReference; 

                protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
                {
                    fileref = new FileReference(); 
                }


                protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    fileref.browse(); 
                    fileref.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelect); 
                }

                private function fileSelect(e:Event):void {
                    try {
                    var data:ByteArray = e.target as ByteArray; 
                    fileref.save(data, "pic1.jpg");             
                    }
                    catch(err:Error) {
                        Alert.show("Error: " + err.message); 
                    }
                }
```

**Edit:**

This was real simple todo:

```
private function fileComplete(e:Event):void {
                if(fileref.data != null) {
                image1.data = fileref.data; 
                }


            }
```

I made a second button which should save the image, and it works fine, but I get the dialog
up, is it really necessary? How can I prevent it and put it explicitly on the servers disc?
**An alternative (I use .NET as a backend) to take the bytearray-image and send it through a .net webservice and let the C# code save the image**. Maybe that's an better option. Actionscript 3 may have some limitations on what it can do, or am I not really informed?

```
protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                fileref = new FileReference(); 
                var data:ByteArray = image1.data as ByteArray; 
                if(data != null) {
                    fileref.save(data); 
                }
                else {
                    Alert.show("Picture is null!");                     
                }

            }
```

This worked well when I took the Webservice approach and stored the Image (= bytearray) in SqlServer.

Comment: can you clarify the question? you want your flex client to upload a file to the server, or do you want to save an image produced by your client to the local disk ?

Comment: I want to save a uploaded image on disk on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to capture an image and upload it you may want to have a look at `ImageSnapshot`.
It will encode the image into either JPEG or PNG. Saving that bytearray will give you more flexibility and decouple the data stored in the server from the client's implementation.